# How to remove trend from estimated variance?

Tags: time-series, variance

I know the initial and final value of a time series over a year, so I can easily calculate the daily geometric average of the growth over that period. I also have an estimate of the daily variance for that year.

But some of the variance will be due to the growth. How should I adjust the estimated variance to remove the effect of growth?

Comment: Ben has suggested that I calculate the variance of the daily growth rather than the variance of the daily data points. I am unable to do this as I do not have access to the daily data. (I obtain the daily average geometric growth by taking the 365th root of the final value divided by the start value).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have a time series of values $X_1, ..., X_n$ that is growing over time.  You can form the corresponding continuous growth rates $\delta_2, ..., \delta_n$ by using standard rate calculations, depending on how you want to measure the rate of growth.

The variation in the values of $X_1, ..., X_n$ is affected by growth over time, and so if you take the sample variance of these values, some of that sample variance will be attributable to growth.  However, the sample variance of the growth rates $\delta_2, ..., \delta_n$ automatically filters out the mean growth rate, and measures the variation in the *rates of growth* rather than the variation in the value of the original series.  Perhaps this is what you're looking for?